# Why php built-in web server doesn't work in this case?

Tags: php, html

When I try to make this code work in built-in php server it doesn't work.

What I try to do is:

1. Run `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 file.php` this command in cmd. Next I type
   `http://localhost:8000` in a browser.
2. After I click the button that should take me to the other site specified in a `file.php` the page clears its content but doesn't change as it should.
   There is a change in adress bar, though.

File 1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body> 
<form action="example.php" method="post">
Count:
<input type="text" name="Example">
<input type="submit" value="Click">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

File 2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<body>
<?php echo $_POST['Example']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _Side note:_ You end self closing html tags with `/>`, not `\>`.

Comment: The internal PHP server always pass all requests to the file you define when starting it. So when the URL changes to `example.php`, it will still go to `file.php`. It's up to your application to check the requested URL and do the correct action depending on the requested URI, just like most frameworks and CMS's.

Comment: So how can this work from command line? Is this possible? (for testing purposes not something that takes too much effort) And how can I define that file?

Comment: You can rename your `file.php` to `index.php` and don't define a file at all when you start the server. Then it should work. [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php): _"If a PHP file is given on the command line when the web server is started it is treated as a "router" script. The script is run at the start of each HTTP request. If this script returns FALSE, then the requested resource is returned as-is. Otherwise the script's output is returned to the browser."_

Comment: I will check it now, and thanks very much for answers :) You're welcome.

Comment: Okay I renamed the file and nothing has changed really :/

Comment: That's strange. I tried it and it worked here. I renamed `file.php` to `index.php`, then I started the server using `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000` (no filename)

Comment: Okay, It works without specyfing the filename. :)

Comment: That's because of the first sentence I posted from the manual: _"If a PHP file is given on the command line when the web server is started it is treated as a "router" script."_

Comment: Yes, I should jump deeper in the manual I guess but thanks again :) You are great!

Comment: I'll post a proper answer so you can close the question by accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) says: *"If a PHP file is given on the command line when the web server is started it is treated as a "router" script"*

That means that if you define `file.php` when you start the web server, *all* requests will target `file.php` and it's up to your application to handle the routing.

If you don't want to do that, you need to rename the start file `file.php` to `index.php` (which is the default file the web server looks for if you don't pass a filename).

Now you can start the server using:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When using a file name for command line web server, you're specifying a *router* script, so you can code yourself your routing strategy in file:

> If a PHP file is given on the command line when the web server is started it is treated as a "router" script. The script is run at the start of each HTTP request. If this script returns FALSE, then the requested resource is returned as-is. Otherwise the script's output is returned to the browser.

via http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

For example, a quick initial hint could be like

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!='/') {
    include($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain how Can I applicate this to script I've presented? I don't really know programming languages well.

Comment: When running `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 file.php` every requests are handled by code from `file.php`; looking at original post, you see an URL change, but executed script is still `file.php`.

You can access variables like `REQUEST_URI` from `$_SERVER` superglobal, since its value reflects the current resource name (like the file path in address bar from _http://localhost:8080/..._ ) , to add or include code from another file.

Comment: I mean, if I add the above code at `file.php` beginning, I can submit the form to `example.php`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know. I'll check it today.